# bash, if then script to parse file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

My requirements is to look through a F-5 config.

Something like:

```
 If x=virtual
 grep for virtual | pool | destination
```

File looks like this:

```
virtual vs_website_443 {
snat automap
pool pl_website_443
destination 11.11.11.11:https
ip protocol tcp
persist pr_cookie_JSESSION_AP
profiles {
   oneconnect-ebiz-blah {}
  pr_http_ebiz_x_forwarded_for {}
   serverssl {
      serverside
  }
   tcp-lan-optimized {}
   wildcard.origin.website.com {
      clientside
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like some of your formatting got messed up. It's hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do.  Can you spend some time on your question please?

Comment: Additionally, what is the expected output?

Comment: you want this: `if [[ "$x" == "virtual" ]]; then grep "virtual\|pool\|destination" file; fi`  ?

Comment: I think what he means is if `x == section`(where in this case section = virtual) then get me the pool and destination (parameters) from that section.

Comment: Yes, I want to search the file, when I see virtual it will then return: virtual  vs_website, pool pl_website, and destination 11.11.11.11

Comment: @user1748054 - The expected output is important enough that it should be included in your question.  Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12902353/edit) and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plain `bash`, though can easily be converted to POSIX sh.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

in=0 # whether we are inside a 'virtual' block
     # such a block ends once we meet a line that starts with '}'

while read -r
do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^virtual ]]; then
        in=1
        echo "${REPLY% *}"
    elif (( in )); then
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^pool ]]
        then echo "$REPLY"
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^destination ]]
        then echo "${REPLY%:*}" # or just "$REPLY" if you want the ':https' part
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^} ]]
        then in=0
        fi
    fi
done < file
```

where *`file`* is your data. You can change that to `"$1"` 
and give the file as an argument to the script.

tested with given data, returns:

```
virtual vs_website_443
pool pl_website_443
destination 11.11.11.11
```

---

using plain `awk`

```
awk '$1 == "virtual" { f=1; print $1,$2; next }         \
     f == 1 { if ($1 == "pool") { print }               \
              else if ($1 == "destination") { print }   \
              else if ($0 ~ /^}/) { f=0 }               \
     }' file
```

with the given data output is:

```
 $ awk '$1 == "virtual" { f=1; print $1,$2; next } f == 1 { if ($1 == "pool") { print } else if ($1 == "destination") { print } else if ($0 ~ /^}/) { f=0 } }' file
virtual vs_website_443
pool pl_website_443
destination 11.11.11.11:https
```

Comment: When I run it against the complete file, change < file to < bigip.conf, it only returns: virtual vs_stage_website_emea_443
virtual vs_stage_website_emea_80
virtual vs_stage_website_global_443
virtual vs_stage_website_global_80
virtual vs_stage_website_latam_443

Comment: well, based on the format of the data you gave as an example it should work. Is the actual data formatted the same way as your example ? are there any leading spaces not present in the example ?

Comment: virtual vs_XXX_www_443 {
   snat automap
   destination xx.xx.xx.xx:https
   ip protocol tcp
   rules short_redirect_xxx_secure
   profiles {
      pr_http_ebiz_x_forwarded_for {}
      serverssl {
         serverside
      }
      tcp-lan-optimized {}
      wildcard.xxx.com {
         clientside
      }
   }
}
virtual vs_xxx_www_80 {
   snat automap
   destination xx.xx.xx.xx:http
   ip protocol tcp
   rules short_redirect_xxx
   persist pr_source_addr_avs
   profiles {
      pr_http_ebiz_x_forwarded_for {}
      tcp-lan-optimized {}

Comment: @user1748054 nope, this is not going to work, comments do not allow formatting. You can however edit your question, and add that there, as ghoti suggested. You can also try the awk version I added in my answer.

Comment: Send me an email, I can send you a sample of the file, see what you think.