# awk script, need to return results on multi lines following keyword

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Using this:

```
awk '$1 == "pool" { f=1; print $1,$2; next }         
     f == 1 { if ($1 == "pool") { print }               
              else if ($1 == "members") { print }   
              else if ($0 ~ /^}/) { f=0 }               
     }' bigip.conf
```

That works fine until the config has the IPs on following lines. 
How can I get it to print the IPs if they are on following lines. 
The config has both, some have it on the same line, some on then next 1, 2 or 3 lines.

the data :

```
    pool pl_stage_xxx_microsites_9483 {
       monitor all tcp_half_open
       members {
          11.11.11.11:9483 {}
          11.22.22.22:9483 {
             session user disabled
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902353/bash-if-then-script-to-parse-file) is the first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing more of your data and your expected output but I think all you need is something like this:

```
awk '
/^}/ { inPool=0 }
$1 == "pool" { inPool=1; inMembers=0 }
inPool {
   if ($1 == "pool") {
      print $1, $2
      print
   }
   else if ($1 == "members") {
      inMembers = 1
   }
   if (inMembers) {
      print
   }
}
' file
```

The above should be a good starting point at least. wrt the other answer posted using getline - getline has some appropriate uses but this isn't one of them, don't use getline until you fully understand and can live with all of it's caveats, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: Here is a bit more date, Running the above works barring it prints the "pool" line twice:                                                                   pool pl_website_443 {
    monitor all tcp_half_open_http
    members 11.22.33.44:https {}
    }
pool pl_website_80 {
   monitor all tcp_half_open
   members {
      11.22.33.44:http {}
      11.22.33.44:http {}
   }
}
pool pl_stage_website_apacretail_9090 {
   monitor all tcp_half_open
   members {
      11.22.33.44:websm {}
      11.22.33.44:websm {}
   }
}

Comment: can't imagine why it'd print the pool line twice. It does print $1 and $2 from the pool line and then the whole pool line just as your originally posted code does. If you don't want that, just remove one of the print lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `awk` code:

```
awk '
$1 == "pool" {
    f=1
    print $1,$2
    next
}         
f == 1 {
    if ($1 == "pool") {
        print
    }               
    else if ($1 == "members") {
        print
        getline
        while ($0 ~ "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5}"){
            print
            getline
        }
     }   
     else if ($0 ~ /^}/) {
         f=0
     }               
 }'
```

That will print the IP lines while they exists.